# Redirect from a directory to a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess

I have a webserver with an the followinf structure : 
www
---diceroller
------web

I would like to redirect any request incoming to /diceroller to /diceroller/web, so the users don't have to type the /web in URL.

At the root of my server is a .htaccess containing the following elements :

```
Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 404 /permalien.php

AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache
```

I tried to use the following .htaccess placed in the diceroller forlder, but I hit a 403 :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^diceroller/(.*)$ /diceroller/web/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Could someone help me to figure this out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RewriteRule's pattern is relative to your current directory. So if your htaccess is located in /diceroller , you have to remove that from the pattern, try the following instead

```
RewriteRule ^((?!web).*)$ /diceroller/web/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Awesome ! It works like a charm. Thank you very much. I thought rewrite rules were always related to root, not the current directory.